# (How) Can I add a custom script to the autoplay options in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, autoplay

Everytime I plug in a certain USB device I usualy need to open a specific webpage to use it.

So I'ld like to do it e.g. in a little batchscript that gets automatically called whenever the device is plugged in.

Unfortunately this is not an option available in the autoplay options of Windows 10.

[image]

However, you can see that e.g. during the installation of `Dropbox` there was an action added to the selection using Dropbox functionality.

So since it seems somehow possible for installers to create an own new entry for autoplay:

**Is there any way to add/install/create my custom action to the autoplay options myself?**

---

**Please note**
I can not install something on the device itself. It has to be on my PC! So I can not use anything that requires e.g. an `autorin.inf` on the USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 does not allow this option any more, because of security.
You now need a third-party product for making it work.

Here are a couple of such products :

## [**APO USB Autorun**](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/APO-USB-Autorun.shtml)

With this freeware product, you may still use the old-style `autorun.inf` :

```
[autorun]
ShellExecute=YOURAPP.exe
UseAutoPlay=1
```

For more detailed information see the article
[How to Auto-Run Windows Programs When You Plug In a USB Drive](https://www.howtogeek.com/326049/how-to-auto-run-windows-programs-when-you-plug-in-a-usb-drive/).

## [**USB Drive Letter Manager**](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html) (USBDLM)

Free for personal and educational use.

You need to create a file named `USBDLM.ini` in the program’s folder (or rename the sample file) and create an entry `AutoRunInf=1` under `[Settings]`:

```
[Settings]
AutoRunInf=1
```

You may then create the matching `autorun.inf` file on the device.

Read More:
[How to Make Windows Autorun USB Flash Drives](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-make-windows-autorun-usb-flash-drives/).

Comment: Hm as I mentioned in my question unfortunately it is not an option for me to install something on the USB device itself. Only on my PC. But both options seem to require something put onto the USB device.

Comment: I think USBDLM can do that with within its configuration file. I have only looked at it briefly, but I think it at the same place where you identify the USBs and their given drive letters, you can also execute a script/program. See the help.

Comment: It seems that it still requires the `autorun.inf` on the USB drive but of course I'll give it a shot anyway. Thanks so far!!